# go to last item in recyclerview

Tags: android

show last item in recyclerview after click .smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1)

does not work correctly

[look at the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysFvq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `setAdapter()` or inside `onClick` function write this code :

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(data.size() - 1);
```

`recyclerView` : is your RecyclerView object

`data` : your ArrayList